# Return only a string instead of two almost identical

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get several links from a webpage, but when I print the result I get:

```
/t54-EXAMPLE-fansub
/t54-EXAMPLE-fansub#55
```

How can I only get only one of those in the output instead of both?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what's the expected output - only the first one? Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```py
>>> '/t54-EXAMPLE-fansub#55'.split('#')  # just to show you the list output
['/t54-EXAMPLE-fansub', '55']
>>> '/t54-EXAMPLE-fansub#55'.split('#')[0]
'/t54-EXAMPLE-fansub'
>>> '/t54-EXAMPLE-fansub'.split('#')[0]
'/t54-EXAMPLE-fansub'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you will have a list called "links" that contains all the links you scraped.

```
links = ["/t54-EXAMPLE-fansub#55","/t54-EXAMPLE-fansub","/t55-EXAMPLE-fansub"]

links = set(map(lambda x:x[:x.index('#')] if '#' in x else x, links))
for link in links:
    print(link)
```

This will change the type of links to a set, be careful about that. This code is just an example implementation of what you can do: Go through the links, strip the part after the first '#' , create a set so that you can keep track of what you already encountered.